# Pop up and Lock Screen Notifications on Android version below 5.0

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

How can I get on screen notifications like the following image?

[image]

I want to make it work on Android Version below 5.0.
I heard i can do it with Fragment but i don't really know how to manage with it.

Comment: Notifications have nothing to do with fragments. There is no OS support for popup or lockscreen notifications prior to Android 5.0. Due to the way you cropped the image, it is unclear exactly what you are showing, but you can create a `RemoteViews` and use that for the content of your `Notification`.

Comment: @CommonsWare , But Facebook display some lockscreen notifications on android below 5.0.

Comment: It is entirely possible that Facebook struck some deals with certain device manufacturers to offer that sort of capability.